# import CSS variable not recognized

Tags: css, angular, import

I have an angular (8.2.12) project that has a css file that defines a lot of styling variables, named `_vars.scss` and it is placed in the `ClientApp\src\scss\` folder. Some variables defined in that file are as below:

```
// NAVBAR

$nav-font-color: black;
$nav-bg-color: white;
```

These styling variables are used by the `nav-menu.component` in the `ClientApp\src\app\nav-menu\nav-menu.component.css` via the `@import` statement as below:

```
@import '../../scss/_vars.scss';
```

There are two problems:

1. It complains about the comment `// NAVBAR`, saying it is invalid, so I have to remove those comment line from that file
2. None of the `$nav-xxx` variables are recognized in the `nav-menu.component.css` file, e.g.

   `.navbar { background: $nav-bg-color; <-- here it complains 'Property value expected', which means the value of that variable was not imported in correctly. }`

Comment: nav-menu.component.css … ? That is a css file, scss vars will only work in scss not in plain css..

Comment: @MikeOne You are right. Please post as Answer.